How to describe Lorentz transformation with magnetic monopole？
We know without magnetic monopoles ,the Lorentz transformation will be: 
$\begin{aligned}\vec{E}'&=\gamma(\vec{E}+\vec{\nu}\times\vec{B})-\frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma+1}\frac{\vec{\nu}}{c}\bigg(\frac{\vec{\nu}}{c}\cdot\vec{E}\bigg),\\\vec{B}'&=\gamma(\vec{B}-\frac{\vec{\nu}\times\vec{E}}{c^2})-\frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma+1}\frac{\vec{\nu}}{c}\bigg(\frac{\vec{\nu}}{c}\cdot\vec{B}\bigg)\end{aligned} $  when with magnetic monopole,how to describe Lorentz covariance transformation and Electromagnetic tensor?

Sorry I don't understand. The EM tensor and its Lorentz transformations don't change when you assume magnetic monopoles. What changes a bit are the Maxwell equations. See for example this post. Since the MEs are tensorial even when magnetic monopoles exist they are Lorentz invariant.

Sorry, I just know the covariant Maxwell function$\sum_{\mu=1}^4\partial_\mu\mathrm{F}{\mu\nu}=-\mu_0\mathrm{i}\nu\quad\partial_\mu\mathrm{F}{\nu\lambda}+\partial\nu\mathrm{F}{\lambda\mu}+\partial\lambda\mathrm{F}_{\mu\nu}=0$  , so I want to know with magnetic monopole, how the EM tensor and the covariant Maxwell function changes in order to fit the new Maxwell function?

I already said that the EM tensor does not change but its symmetries will. Your second equation is a Bianchi identity and part of the Maxwell equation without monopoles. With magnetic monopole its RHS will be $-\mu_0\mathbf{i}_m,.$ See the usual suspect where they explain what the magnetic current $\mathbf{i}_m$ is and use a notation you might be more familiar with.
